# Issue with leOS2 for one-time tasks

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c, interrupt

I'm trying to use the last version of **leOS2 scheduler from Leonardo Miliani** ( https://github.com/leomil72/leOS2 ) but I have a strange behavior with a very simplistic ONETIME task.

Platform : Arduino Uno clone, so Atmel Atmega 328P CPU.

My code is very straightforward :

```
#include "leOS2.h"
leOS2 myOS; //create a new istance of the class leOS

bool test = true;

void setup()
{
    myOS.begin(); //initialize the scheduler
}
void loop()
{
    // Do some stuff ...

    if(test)
    {
       DoAndUndo(3000);
       test = false;
    }
}

void DoAndUndo(unsigned long duration)
{
    doSomething();

    myOS.addTask(cancelTheThing, myOS.convertMs(duration), ONETIME);
}


void doSomething()
{
    Serial.println("thing on");
}

void cancelTheThing()
{
    Serial.println("thing is off");
}
```

In case it can be some kind of conflict, my code also relies on the following :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
```

The problem is :
        myOS.addTask(cancelTheThing, myOS.convertMs(duration), ONETIME);
is supposed to call asynchronously the "cancelTheThing" method 3 seconds later, and for only one time, and then forget it.
But for an unknown reason, it's called after the expected delay, **but it loops infinitely on this method** ! In the example case above, my serial stream is filled with a lot of "thing is off" messages, and the µc is unresponsive to anything apart a reset.

The call to DoAndUndo() will produce a such like output :

```
 thing on
```

And 3s later, in a very fast infinite loop :

```
 thing is off
 thing is off
 thing is off
 thing is off
```

If I remove the "ONETIME" flag, the task is called every three seconds (exactly as it's suppose to do, so the scheduler works, but it's not what I want in my use case).

note : As a try of workaround, I've tried some tricks like calling haltScheduler() inside my cancelTheThing() and reenable it with restartScheduler() in DoAndUndo(), and also tried to call removeTask once it has ran, but it didn't help.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a fault with the library whereby if the only registered task is a one-shot task it doesn't get cancelled when it has executed.

Adding another periodic task in `setup()` (say to blink an LED every 500ms) so there are now 2 tasks instead of one works around the problem.

The way the system is written it will always try an execute task number 0 even when there are 0 tasks registered because they erroneously used a "do {...} while" construct instead of a "while { ...}" construct.

---

I  have filed a bug report, corrected the error, and raised a pull request with the fix in it.  Until it gets accepted you can obtain the fixed version here: https://github.com/majenkotech/leOS2

Comment: Hello, thanks to have answered but it's not the solution. The above sample was not accurate (I've edited it, sorry for the lack of precision). The "infinite loop" issue I encounter effectively comes from the scheduler as I explained, not a such trivial issue as you thought. If it was a so simple mistake, my "doSomething" method would have loop too...

Comment: @AFract If you want our help you will have to provide a piece of code that compiles and executes exactly as shown and demonstrates the problem. An approximation is of no use at all.

Comment: And the one in first post should be ok. The original code was only slightly different, i just add an "if" to show that the true one doesn't do what you thought. And even without it, the explanation below it were already enoughly clear to make you figure your answer cannot help to fix the issue.

Comment: @AFract What you write below your code describes precisely what I would expect from the original code you posted. Now you have changed the code so it doesn't compile it is of no use at all.  What is "test"?

Comment: It's an EXAMPLE. What you need to focus on is : When i call "DoAndUndo(3000);" ONE time it continuously executes cancelTheThing() instead of just calling it once, as the ONETIME flag passed to the scheduler should do. Exactly like explained in the post content.

Comment: With your **ORIGINAL** code I would expect that to happen since the way it was written you were *CONSTANTLY* creating the task over and over again.  Now with this code it's not the case because you added *something* that hasn't been defined.  **WITHOUT KNOWING WHAT THAT IS WE CANNOT HELP YOU!!!**

Comment: The question was clear, the code sample is here to illustrate the use I do of leOS. Maybe if you had read it instead of posting ironical-useless answers like "Here's a hint... What do you think the name of this function signifies...?", you'd have notice it. To be kind with you, I changed the sample to make it build and behave "as you want" till the part with the scheduler. To be clear : the problem does not look to be in the algorithm, it's in the behavior of the scheduling lib.

Comment: It's **NOT** "to keep me happy"!  It is to make it physically possible for us (NOT JUST ME) to HELP you!  Quite frankly, to be brutally honest, I really don't know if I can be bothered now.  You probably won't listen to the answer because apparently you already know everything!

Comment: @AFract Incidentally, you clearly haven't even tried running the code you have posted, since it still CAN NOT work.

Comment: I can't upload it right now to the Arduino (I don't have it here) but it builds well for me. But the point is really simple :     "myOS.addTask(cancelTheThing, myOS.convertMs(duration), ONETIME);" doesn't do what its documentation suggests : instead of calling cancelTheThing one time, it locks up in infinite loop. If the original author of the lib or somebody who knows it well read my msg, he could probably have an hint about the problem.

Comment: @AFract Now that I have re-written your program so that it actually works, I can replicate your results - something that I couldn't have done before.  Now I can actually analyse the problem and find the cause.

Comment: I didn't "rewrite" it and I didn't change the example since 20 minutes. But nevermind, thanks for your help and your efforts. I'm glad to see you meet the same issue than me, even on a so simple example.

Comment: No, I had to re-write it.  I have traced the problem and found a workaround for it - I have also corrected the underlying problem and raised a bug report and pull request with the repository.  More info in my answer.

Comment: Wow ! great work of debugging. I'll try it ASAP, I hope your pull request will be accepted. I'll tell you if it's effectively ok with your little change.